# Firebase - Functions does not allow me to set region

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to set a region to deploy my functions. According to the documentation I have to do:

```
var functions = firebase.app().functions('us-west2');
```

But when I do this and then try to deploy I get an error:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'onCall' of undefined
```

If I change functions definitions back to default:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
```

It works, any ideas why I get this error?

Sample Code:
    const firebase = require("firebase");
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    require("firebase-functions");

```
firebase.initializeApp({...})

admin.initializeApp()

let functions = firebase.app().functions('us-east1')

exports.findUserInAuth = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {..}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to provide the complete, minimal code needed to reproduce this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson I just added sample code

Comment: Your sample code doesn't declare `firebase`, so it doesn't look complete to me. Also I'm not sure why you would require firebase-funcitons without doing something with the object it returns.  You need that to build your Cloud Function defintion.

Comment: Forgot to copy first line, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're reading the documentation incorrectly.

If this is a most basic definition of a callable function, as suggested by the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable):

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
exports.findUserInAuth = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

Then, to change the region, you need to insert some more method calls in the builder for that function:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
exports.findUserInAuth = functions.https.region('us-west2').onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

The code on the frontend client will **not** use firebase-functions.  You have to use the [instructions for setting up the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#set_up_your_client_development_environment) later on that page.  Setting the region on the client works differently.